# WIA getting error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, wia

I am getting error after select scanner device for document scanning:
Here is my code:

```html
public ImageFile Scan()
        {
            ImageFile image;
            try
            {
                CommonDialog dialog = new CommonDialog();
                image = dialog.ShowAcquireImage(
                        WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType,
                        WiaImageIntent.ColorIntent,
                        WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality,
                        WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatJPEG,
                        false,
                        true,
                        false);
                return image;
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                if (ex.ErrorCode == -2145320939)
                {
                    throw new ScannerNotFoundException();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ScannerException("COM Exception", ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

OS: Windows 8 Pro 64bit
IDE: VIsual Studio 2012
Language: C#
Technology: WPF
Library: Interop.WIA 2.0

In wpf project I select Any CPU Platform target.
Sometime getting "Retrieving COM class factory failed" error before device select dialog box appearing.

-Is this support WIA 2.0 32 and 64bit any OS.
-Is this support duplex scanning using WIA 2.0

Sometime its work fine, sometime get errors. So what I need to do?

Comment: E_FAIL is only a teacher's grade for the quality of the error reporting, it tells you absolutely nothing about the root problem.  You need to get your machine stable again, probably requires shopping for a driver update for the scanner.  Or junking it because you didn't spend enough money on it and you'll never get it reliable.

Comment: I gone through C# Wia Scanning in WPF application, see the below url:
http://10rem.net/blog/2010/01/08/scanning-images-in-wpf-via-wia

I want to build C# WIA Scanning in WPF application. 
 
- Duplex Scan ( WIA 2.0 ), 
- Support all devices ( required Canon ImageFormula DR-130C ), 
- Run on 32 and 64bit OS ( eg. Win XP, Vista, 7, 8, 10 etc ).

I am working with on below environment:
OS: WIndows 8 Pro 64bit
IDE: Visual Studio 2012 Professional
Language: C# 3.5
Framework: 4.5
Library: Windows Image Acquisition or WIA 2.0
Scanner Device: Canon ImageFormula DR-130C

Comment: WIA 2.0 is not supported duplex scanning, not supported to some Operating System, as well as some scanner devices. So can you please tell me pros and cons of WIA Automation Library 2.0